# Why does btrfs scrub process more data than allocated?

Tags: linux, btrfs

Why is the "**Total to scrub**" a lot bigger than "**Device Allocated**".

**29.1TiB** vs **21.24TiB** is a huge difference.

Setup: I have a btrfs raid array. It has a mixed data chunks of RAID1 and RAID5, due to a not complete conversion. But as I have read, this does not harm.

```
btrfs f u -T .
Overall:
    Device size:                  54.57TiB
    Device allocated:             21.24TiB
    Device unallocated:           33.33TiB
    Device missing:                  0.00B
    Used:                         20.52TiB
    Free (estimated):             31.00TiB      (min: 8.99TiB)
    Data ratio:                       1.10
    Metadata ratio:                   4.00
    Global reserve:              512.00MiB      (used: 64.00KiB)
```

```
btrfs scrub status .
UUID:             yaya
Scrub started:    Sun Apr  3 01:15:01 2022
Status:           running
Duration:         55:56:56
Time left:        12:46:52
ETA:              Tue Apr  5 21:58:54 2022
Total to scrub:   29.10TiB
Bytes scrubbed:   23.69TiB
Rate:             123.33MiB/s
Error summary:    no errors found
```

```
btrfs fi df .
Data, RAID1: total=10.58TiB, used=10.21TiB
Data, RAID5: total=8.68TiB, used=8.58TiB
System, RAID1C4: total=32.00MiB, used=2.42MiB
Metadata, RAID1C4: total=23.00GiB, used=22.02GiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=512.00MiB, used=0.00B
```

```
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Versions: btrfs-progs v5.4.1
Kernel: 5.13.0-39-generic #44~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP
```

Comment: How much data is in RAID5 chunks, specifically?

Comment: I added the data above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the RAID1 data is reported as half of the total space,
by not including the mirror size.

This means that its real size is 10.58 x 2 = 21.16 TiB.
If you now add the RAID5 size of 8.68 TiB, the total is 29.84.

This is larger than 29.10 TiB, but perhaps the scrub has already
processed some of this data.

The "Total to scrub" seems correct.
The "Device allocated" is perhaps false because of the RAID.

Comment: This means the "allocated" value is wrong? Is this a known bug?

Comment: It's not wrong, just calculated differently because of the RAID.

Comment: Hmm, I assumed the "allocated" value is a fact - the amount of allocated space on a drive, no matter which raid level is assigned to the chunk. But different tools seem to map the raid level on it, which messes it up. "btrfs f u -T" for example shows the pure allocated values in the table - but the "Total" applies the raid level. The unallocated seems to be "pure"